# Update column from table starting from 0

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a SQL Server Docs Table with two fields, Idx1 and Idx2:

```
Idx1      Idx2
 0         23
 1         34
 2         12
 4          1
 5         21
 7         45
 8         50
 9          3 
10          9
...        ...
```

Note that numbers in Idx1 column are unique, they are never repeated.

And now I am trying to re-number Idx1 column starting from 0, that is, 0,1,2,3,4,... and so on.

The expected result should be:

```
Idx1      Idx2
 0         23
 1         34
 2         12
 3          1
 4         21
 5         45
 6         50
 7          3 
 8          9
...        ...
```

I have tried below and it works:

```
DECLARE @myVar int
SET @myVar = 0

UPDATE
  Docs
SET
  @myvar = Idx1 = @myVar + 1
```

but i am worried about in which order SQL Server are numbering them. I would like to explicitly order them first by Idx1 column and then re-number them taking into account this order.

**NOTE**: I am using SQL Server 2008

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no need to play around with variables. You could make a subquery and apply sorting inside it to be certain it follows explicit order. There's alternative, modern, approach, which will also work in other database engines supporting window functions.

Use `ROW_NUMBER` window function available from SQL Server 2008 to create a column with temporary (for the query run) sequence based on `order by` argument. Then substract `1` from it to make it start from `0`.

```
UPDATE docs
SET idx1 = t.rn
FROM (
  SELECT idx1, row_number() over (order by idx1) - 1 as rn
  FROM docs
) t
WHERE docs.idx1 = t.idx1
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply use `row_number()` function :

```
with t as (
     select *, (row_number() over (order by idx1))-1 seq
     from docs
)

update t 
     set t.idx1 = t.seq
from t inner join
     docs t1
     on t1.idx1 = t.idx1;
```